# How to animate the modal page navigation transitions in native script

Tags: nativescript

I have set the animated property of the modal page to true, but its not working

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=6xzzC2&v=2

I'm trying to scale up and down modal page during popup of modal.

Comment: You will have to extend the Transition class and write a native animation as these are platform specific. Here is an [example](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/transition/fade-transition.ios.ts) for Fade animation from the core framework.

Comment: @Manoj thank you. i want to implement it for android and i tried this fade-transition.android.ts but not succeed. can you guide me on which page i need to write the code and how. can you give some more information in steps.

Comment: Just realised transitions do not work for modal. It's not supported, you might have to override the native dialog fragment implementation Or configure the animation on your Android theme.

Answer (score 0):

It's referenced like a bug here : [[BUG] Issue with ModalPage animation.](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5989)